# WordPress import only 332 users out of 526?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to import my WordPress .xml backup. File is just 170 kb and have 526 users (confirmed in backup file). All ends good, no errors but only 332 users are imported to new website.

I've notice some errors first (included below) but after that fix (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/24373/24373.diff) no errors after import but still 332 imported. What can be wrong? max_execution_time, max_input_time and memory_limit set to super high and still nothing.

> [27-Apr-2015 06:57:03 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Redefining already defined constructor for class WXR_Parser_Regex in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/parsers.php on line 408
>
> [27-Apr-2015 06:57:03 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of WP_Import::bump_request_timeout() should be compatible with WP_Importer::bump_request_timeout($val) in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php on line 38

[image]

526 after .xml upload... 322 after submit.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini option max_input_vars was commented. I've removed the comment and added a high value. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Comment out the old constructor function (lines 404 to 406) in `parsers.php`

2.In wordpress-importer.php (line 1110) replace this line:

```
function bump_request_timeout()
```

with this line

```
function bump_request_timeout( $val )
```